# To sum elements of array between a range of index, what would be best way to do it in PHP?

Tags: php

Lets say for $numArr = array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100);
how to sum between specific range like 30 - 60 to get sum of 180.. (30+40+50+60).

edit : This is my latest code

```
<?php
function sum_array ($no1, $no2){
$array = array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100);
$input = array_slice($array, $no1, $no2);
return array_sum($input);
}
echo sum_array(0,3);
?>
```

I made a basic function for this according to u guys replies .. though still i want to put some validations into this like the parameters should be positive else the function should return -1 .. and what if the second index of the range is not in array.. like (90-120). Would it able to still sum what's in range and in array .. and give 190 to the above range.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not filter the list for all elements that are within that range, and then sum them up?

Comment: Do you want to specify the range by index, or by the values? And if the later, are the values always properly sorted in ascending order?

Comment: I know it somehow needs to be done with array_sum, but not sure how to specify the range

Comment: The range needs to be specified by index .. does the array still needs to be sorted ?

Comment: If you want to filter by index, use array_slice(). If you want to filter by value, use array_filter(). Then use array_sum() on the result.

Comment: array_sum doesn't support selecting specific elements only. If you want to use array_sum, then you need to extract the range into a new array first. The alternative would be that you simply loop over your array items, and manually sum up only the relevant ones. If you do that with a `for` loop, you can make that start and stop at your range boundaries to begin with.

Comment: And what if the second index of the range in not in array.. like (90-120). Would it able to still sum what's in range and in array .. and give 190 to the above range.

Comment: "And what if the second index of the range in not in array" - that depends on how you code your algorithm. Please share your attempts

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

```
$numArr = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 ];
$startValue = 30;
$endValue = 60;

$startIndex = array_search($startValue, $numArr);
$endIndex = array_search($endValue, $numArr);
$length = $endIndex - $startIndex + 1;
$result = array_sum(array_slice($numArr, $startIndex, $length));

print_r($result);
```